# how do I change the background of my active <li> in twitter bootstrap nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

Ok so I have a standard twitter bootstrap nav and I just wanted to change the background color of the active link when it is selected such as Home or Contact us.. Rite now if you are in a certain page the background of the li in the navigation bar is just plain black to demonstrate that it is selected. I wanted it to be blue.
Here is the code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="brand" href="#">Logo</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse text-center">
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
              <li class="active" id="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I hear you would put something like .nav > li > a:active {background:blue} but that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a:active
```

Is wrong for what you're trying to achieve

The :active pseudo selector - *A link becomes active when you click on it.*

Try

```
.nav .active { background:blue }
```

The > symbol will select the direct child element.

Comment: that still did not work. The li in the ul still has the little black box as a background when active in the navigation bar.

Comment: You might need to add !important to the rule.

As



    .navbar-inverse .nav .active > a, .navbar-inverse .nav .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .nav .active > a:focus {
        background-color: #111111;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

Might be overriding it

Comment: I did .nav .active { background:blue !important;} and still not changing the li background color to blue

Comment: Try 

    .nav .active a { background:blue!important }

Comment: That worked! thanks. I found out 2 methods that worked .nav .active a { background:#blue!important } or just repeating .navbar-inverse .nav .active > a, .navbar-inverse .nav .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .nav .active > a:focus { background-color: #blue; color: #FFFFFF; }

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
<style>
#home.active, #contract.active{
    background-color : blue
}

</style>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="brand" href="#">Logo</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse text-center">
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                <li class="active" id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li id="contract"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .nav .active a { background:#blue!important } did the trick. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Add following javascript to update active tab by highlight

```
$('ul.nav > li').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to target the `a` element inside of the active `li` for the color to change

```
.active a {
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav-fixed=top>li.active>a
{
    //styling
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.